# Multiline regex - how to match a sentence?

Tags: php, regex

I need help extracting states from the following text:

```
    <br>
    From: Florida
    <br>


    <br>

        New York, Texas, California<br>



        10% Delay chance
        <br>
```

It's just part of a larger document, so there may be other occurrences of `<br>`, thus I can't rely on their count. However, there is only 1 occurrence of the following pattern: `From:.+<br>.+<br>.+(.+).+% Delay chance<br>`. Using PHP:

```
$pattern = "/.+From:.+<br>.+<br>.+(.+).+% Delay chance<br>/ism";
```

Comment: What language/engine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking the community to act as OP's personal regex generator.

Comment: If your goal is to just find all state names you could compile a RegEx "whitelist" of sorts like so: `Florida|New York|Texas|California`. Without knowing the language it's impossible to help you implement it but you should be able to do that on your own (with minimal effort) regardless.

Comment: Depending on the regex engine, you might add the `s` modifier. Otherwise replace all dots with `[\s\S]`, well that also depends on the engine :)

Comment: If you only want the sentence, then eliminate all "<br>", trim each line, and eliminate newlines (perhaps putting a single space between each...). No searching necessary.

Comment: Updated the question. PHP.

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. Without knowing what you're actually trying to do here it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Use something like `/from:(?:.*?<br>){2}\s*([^<]+).*?% delay chance/is` make your quantifiers [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) by putting a `?` behind. Matches in capture group `$1`

Comment: @freefaller [Stop linking to such obvious rants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant), it's not helpful.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the campaign to stop it being used, @HamZa.  I still stand by the statement, but will remove the link (as it's over 5 minutes I will create a new comment)

Comment: Rule 1: don't use regex to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with regex, see rule 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one offered a solution except for (not really helpful) comments to avoid parsing HTML, here is what I came up with in the end:

```
$string = preg_replace ( "/\s+/" , " " , $string );
preg_match("!(?:.*?\K<br>){3}(?P<states>.*?)<br>!", $string, $match);
```

`$match['states']` will contain the states.